# Error: This site can’t be reached while installing laravel 5.7 on CENT OS7

Tags: linux, centos7, laravel-5.6, laravel-5.7, linode

I am trying to configure CENT OS 7 to deploy laravel code. I followed below approach but getting error:

This site can’t be reached, took too long to respond. Below are the commands ran.

```
1. yum update
```

## PHP Installation

```
2. yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
3. yum install yum-utils
4. yum install http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
5. yum-config-manager --enable remi-php72
6. yum install php72 php72-php-fpm php72-php-mysqlnd php72-php-opcache php72-php-xml php72-php-xmlrpc php72-php-gd php72-php-mbstring php72-php-json
```

## Starting Services

```
7. yum install httpd
8. service httpd start
```

## Installing composer

```
9. rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
10. curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php72
11. mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
12. chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Finally created a folder with the name of Laravel in www folder and placed all root files/folders. Also placed folers/files belongs to public folder inside html folder.

```
13. Restarted the services. service httpd restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should have all Laravel project folders together in the same folder, and set root to the *public* folder. For example, all folders should be in the html folder.

You likely broke the locations.

Answer (score 0):

The error you mentioned

> This site can’t be reached, took too long to respond

is due to the firewall lacking instructions to allow connections to the port 80 (or 443 if you are using https).

You need to run the following commands to instruct the firewall to allow traffic to the standard http/https ports (if you don't plan on using https, don't run the second command):

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=http
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=https
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

The first and second command add the rules, while the third makes sure the firewall reloads the rules so that it is aware of the additions.

---

These being said, you still need some more configuration to enable a Laravel application to function.

Comment: Is there any way to check the error logs? I am still facing the same problem.